# Why doesn't std::lock_guard/std::unique_lock use type erasure?

Tags: c++, multithreading, type-erasure

Why do [`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) and [`std::unique_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock) necessitate specifying the lock type as a template parameter?

Consider the following alternative. First, in a `detail` namespace, there are type erasure classes (a non-template abstract base class, and a template derived class):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

namespace detail {

    struct locker_unlocker_base {
        virtual void lock() = 0;
        virtual void unlock() = 0;
    };

    template<class Mutex>
    struct locker_unlocker : public locker_unlocker_base {
        locker_unlocker(Mutex &m) : m_m{&m} {}
        virtual void lock() { m_m->lock(); }
        virtual void unlock() { m_m->unlock(); }
        Mutex *m_m;
    };
}
```

Now `te_lock_guard`, the type erasure lock guard, simply placement-news an object of the correct type when constructed (without dynamic memory allocation):

```
class te_lock_guard {
public:
    template<class Mutex>
    te_lock_guard(Mutex &m) {
        new (&m_buf) detail::locker_unlocker<Mutex>(m);
        reinterpret_cast<detail::locker_unlocker_base *>(&m_buf)->lock();
    }
    ~te_lock_guard() {
        reinterpret_cast<detail::locker_unlocker_base *>(&m_buf)->unlock();
    }

private:
    std::aligned_storage<sizeof(detail::locker_unlocker<std::mutex>), alignof(detail::locker_unlocker<std::mutex>)>::type m_buf;
};
```

I've checked the performance vs. the standard library's classes:

```
int main() {
    constexpr std::size_t num{999999};
    {
        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        for(size_t i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
            std::mutex m;
            te_lock_guard l(m);
        }
        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end= std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - begin).count() << std::endl;
    }
    {
        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        for(size_t i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
            std::mutex m;
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m);
        }
        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end= std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - begin).count() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Using g++ with `-O3`, there is no statistically-significant performance loss.

Comment: what is `statistically-significant` for you? The native implementation seemed faster after running it 4-5 times. So not sure what you see as insignificant. And why choose a default implementation which is slower than the current alternative? The question itself is pretty interessting though. Good someone measured an alternative.

Comment: If you really were just too upset by having to type the type name again, you could use a function template: `auto && lock = guard_me(mx);` ([Demo](https://ideone.com/ysxJEz).)

Comment: @Hayt What I meant is that a statistical permutation test did not reject the hypotheses that they are from the same distribution. By me, the complicated alternative indeed is sometimes faster, incidentally. Dealing in statistics, I try to avoid strong statements such as "they run at the same speed".

Comment: @KerrekSB That is also true, thanks.

Comment: @AmiTavory ah ok. I have just run this a few times on cpp.sh where the second one ran always faster sometimes the first approach was up to 50% slower. Usually inheritance should be more slower than compiler generated code but this can depend on platform/compiler-version sure. When it sometimes had been the other way round for you I can see the reason for this statement.

Comment: Maybe a good time to make a general point: Runtime polymorphism is primarily useful when you genuinely *do not know* the desired type until runtime. What you're describing is essentially just implementation convenience, and that doesn't *require* runtime logic; other implementation strategies exist.

Comment: Can you specialize `std::lock_guard`?  Is that useful, as yours cannot be (practically).  Do all implementations guarantee pointer to base can be gotten by reinterpreting address passed to placement new?  The size of lock guard in C++11 is one pointer: yours is going to be two.  Is that a concern?  Do all instances of lock guard end up the same size on all supported platforms?  There is a platform where certian pointers are larger.

Comment: @Yakk Those are all very interesting points, thanks! In any case, I think Vittorio Romeo's answer pretty much clinches the whole thing.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Because this complicates the implementation for no significant benefit whatsoever, and hides the fact that `std::lock_guard` and `std::unique_lock` are aware of the type of the lock they're guarding at compile-time.

Your solution is a workaround for the fact that class template parameter deduction does not happen during construction - this is addressed in the upcoming standard.

Necessitating to specify the lock type is annoying boilerplate that will be solved in C++17 *(not only for lock guards)* thanks to the [Template parameter deduction for constructors **(P0091R3)**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0091r3.html) proposal.

The proposal *(which was accepted)*, allows template parameters to be deduced from constructors, removing the need for `make_xxx(...)` helper functions or explicitly specify typenames that the compiler should be able to deduce:

```
// Valid C++17
for(size_t i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
    std::mutex m;
    std::unique_lock l(m);
}
```

Comment: That's very interesting. Thanks for the link.

Comment: I believe that this revision is better worded and corrected in some places (typos etc.) http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0091r2.html. Although I cannot find information on which one was actually accepted.

Comment: @Patryk: thanks, p0091r3 is the adopted one [according to this page](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/#mailing2016-07)

Answer (score 10):

Roll on [C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17)... In the meantime, there is no need for type-erasure. Template function argument deduction allows us an easy helper:

```
template<class Mutex>
auto make_lock(Mutex& m)
{
    return std::unique_lock<Mutex>(m);
}

...

std::mutex m;
std::recursive_mutex m2;

auto lock = make_lock(m);
auto lock2 = make_lock(m2);
```

Comment: Yeah, and it's the option everyone has been using until C++17, including the stdlib itself, so I'm surprised you hadn't seen it before. :P